# Blending DataFrames in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am having trouble figuring out how to "blend" two DataFrames. What I am after is filling out the "missing" values in DataFrame `df_A` with values found in a similar DataFrame `df_B`. I have tried different versions of `join`
 but obviously not come up with a result as of yet.

Moreover,

E.g.

```
dict_a = {'ID' : ['id_a', 'id_b', 'id_c', 'id_c'], 'A': ['Hello', 2, 3, 3], 'B': [3, 4, 5, 55], 'C': [11, 'World', 15, 25], 'Date': ['2018-10-23', '2018-10-23', '2018-10-23', '2018-10-24']}
dict_b = {'ID' : ['id_c', 'id_a'], 'A': [np.nan, 31], 'B': [np.nan, 55], 'C': [11, np.nan], 'Date': ['2018-10-23', '2018-10-23']}

df_A = pd.DataFrame(data=dict_a)
df_B = pd.DataFrame(data=dict_b)

>> df_A
>>               A  B      C    ID    Date
          0  Hello  3     11    id_a  2018-10-23
          1      2  4  World    id_b  2018-10-23
          2      3  5     15    id_c  2018-10-23
          3      3  55    25    id_c  2018-10-24

>> df_B
>>               A  B      C    ID    Date
          0    NaN  NaN   11.0  id_c  2018-10-23
          1   31.0  55.0  NaN   id_a  2018-10-23
```

Desired result should look like (pseudo-code)

```
>> df_blended = df_B.values if df_A.isnan() else df_A.values where df_A.ID = df_B.ID and df_A.Date= df_B.Date
>> df_blended
>>               A  B      C    ID    Date
          0      3  5    11.0  id_c  2018-10-23
          1   31.0  55.0  11   id_a  2018-10-23
```

So, prioritize df_B, secondly using df_A. Hope it's understandable!

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df = df_B.combine_first(df_A)
print (df)

       A     B      C
0  Hello  32.0     11
1     22   4.0  World
2     31  55.0     15
```

Or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), but all data are converted to strings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df_B.isnull(), df_A, df_B), index=df_A.index, columns=df_A.columns)
print (df)

       A   B      C
0  Hello  32     11
1     22   4  World
2     31  55     15
```

EDIT: First [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with default inner join, then select columns with `rename` and use `combine_first`:

```
df = df_B.merge(df_A, on=['ID','Date'], suffixes=('','_'))

cols = df.columns[df.columns.str.endswith('_')]
df = df[df_B.columns].combine_first(df[cols].rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip('_')))

print (df)
      A     B     C        Date    ID
0   3.0   5.0  11.0  2018-10-23  id_c
1  31.0  55.0  11.0  2018-10-23  id_a
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
    df_blended =df_B.fillna(df_A)
    df_blended
```

output

```
    A       B   C
0   Hello   32  11
1   22      4   World
2   31      55  15
```

Comment: this one doesn't take into account the matching of 'ID' and 'Date' columns